# Digilent adept crash

Tags: fpga, ubuntu-15.10

when I launch this on a terminal `djtgcfg enum` to read my board (Basys 2) it will return this error:

> djtgcfg: pthread_mutex_unlock.c:87: __pthread_mutex_unlock_usercnt: Assertio ntype == PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK_NP' failed. Core dump created

What does it mean? I've no ideas. My OS is Ubuntu 15.10 64 bit.